# How to return view with hashtag in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, hashtag

After saving user, I want to return to the same tab in the page with success message. How do I add hashtag in the view path or route path in laravel

```
if($user->save()){
    $success = "User Registered";
    return View::make('user')->with('success', $success);
```

When I try this, it gives me an error :-

```
return View::make('user#adduser')->with('success', $success);

View [user#adduser] not found
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the url that will render the view with `route('user')` and append a hash at the end of it.

So, the redirect could be:

```
return Redirect::to( route('user') . '#adduser')->with('success', $success);
```

Of course you'll need a proper set up to show the view from the route returned by `route('user')`:  a `routes.php` entry and controller method to to show the view

Something like this:

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('user', 'UserController@show');
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function show()
{
     return View::make('user');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that is possible, you can use a redirect to go to the page with hash and the success message:

```
return Redirect::to('user#adduser')->with('success', $success);
```

Comment: tried this, getting an error -  NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Comment: You have to redirect to the correct route, i just assumed a route for the example. Can you add the user specific routes file to the Question?

Comment: Route::resource('user', 'UserController'); - this page has 4 tabs, i want to open some specific tab after some data is stored.

Comment: Works fine in my small test case, can you please update your first post with more info? Like your route file, your UserController file with used methods?